# Regex - Strip out commas and spaces from 'empty' address fields

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a third party address lookup service that provides address data in the following format:

`'addr line one, , , , city, county, postcode, addr line one, addr line two, , , city, county, postcode, addr line one, , , , city, county, postcode, addr line one, addr line two, addr line three, addr line four, city, county, postcode'`

As you can see from the data, often there are 'empty' fields that are still delimited by a comma followed by a space.

The input string is split into individual address records:

`'addr line one, , , , city, county, postcode'`

`'addr line one, addr line two, , , city, county, postcode'`

`'addr line one, , , , city, county, postcode'`

`'addr line one, addr line two, addr line three, addr line four, city, county, postcode'`

I am looking to produce the following output:

`'addr line one, city, county, postcode'`

`'addr line one, addr line two, city, county, postcode'`

`'addr line one, city, county, postcode'`

`'addr line one, addr line two, addr line three, addr line four, city, county, postcode'`

I would imagine that a regex would be a good solution, but I am at a loss as to how to create a regex that would filter this string correctly.

Comment: So every run of just commas and spaces should be replace with a single comma and space?

Comment: Were the spaces in this part of the string an error? `addr line two ,` and `addr line three ,` (space between the word and comma).

Comment: Apologies. Yes the spaces were typos. edited and corrected.

Comment: Yes scott (unfortunately I can't control the output).

Comment: Question edited to be more focussed

Comment: I don't think you want to remove consecutive commas.  Instead I think you should read 7 fields at a time.  The first 4 are address lines, and then there is a city, county and postcode field.  That way you keep the records straight.  You can concatenate the address lines with newline characters if you wish, then `.trim()` them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of these two regex patterns should clean up 'empty' fields in address data:

---

**1. Remove consecutive *comma-space(s)* pattern**

- `\s+` → `, , , , , ,`
- `\s+` → `,   , ,   ,     , ,`

```js
const address = 'addr line one, , , , city, county, postcode, ...';
const commaSpaceRegex = /(,\s+(?=,))+/g;
console.log(address.replace(commaSpaceRegex, ''));
```

- [Diagram](https://regexper.com/#%2F%28%2C%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3D%2C%29%29%2B%2Fg)

[image: Consecutive commas with spaces regex pattern diagram]

- [Explanation](https://regexr.com/7p7u5)

[image: Consecutive commas with spaces regex pattern explanation]

---

**2. Remove all consecutive commas - with or without space(s)**

- `\s*` → `, , , , , ,`
- `\s*` → `,,,,,,`
- `\s*` → `,, , ,   ,,`

```js
const address = 'addr line one, , , , city, county, postcode, ...';
const allCommasRegex = /(,\s*(?=,))+/g;
console.log(address.replace(allCommasRegex, ''));
```

- [Diagram](https://regexper.com/#%2F%28%2C%5Cs*%28%3F%3D%2C%29%29%2B%2Fg)

[image: All consecutive commas regex pattern diagram]

- [Explanation](https://regexr.com/7p7rt)

[image: All consecutive commas regex pattern explanation]

Comment: This is an incredible answer. Thank you for a clear explanation of the regex and it's process.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the line into an array, filter out empty elements, and then join the valid ones back together:

```
var test = 'addr line one, , , , city, county, postcode, addr line one, addr line two, , , city, county, postcode, addr line one, , , , city, county, postcode, addr line one, addr line two, addr line three, addr line four, city, county, postcode';

var parts = test.split(/,/);
console.log(parts);
arr = parts.filter(function(entry) { return /\S/.test(entry); });
var newString = arr.join(",");
console.log(newString);
```

However... I think you are messing with your data. They are multiple address lines within multiple addresses with a structure:

- addr line 1
- addr line 2
- addr line 3
- addr line 4
- city
- county
- postcode

Not every address in there has lines 2-4 (Apt B, Suite 1234, etc), so they are blank, not errors.
If you just get rid of them, then "city" becomes "addr line two"

What I think you want to do is split the line into groups of 7, each group being the full address of one specific address - whether the additional addr lines are filled out or not.